# Function for retrieving own ip address from within R?

Tags: r

Does anyone know of an R function that is able to retrieve one's own IP address (of the PC you're working on)? It would be very helpful! Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can issue a `system()` command to your operating system:

- In Windows you can use `ipconfig`
- In Linux, use `ifconfig`

For example, on Windows try calling `system()` with the argument `intern=TRUE` to return the results to R:

```
x <- system("ipconfig", intern=TRUE)
```

This returns:

```
x
 [1] ""                                                                   
 [2] "Windows IP Configuration"                                           
 [3] ""                                                                   
 [4] ""                                                                   
 [5] "Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:"                  
 [6] ""                                                                   
 [7] "   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : tbglondon.local"             
 [8] "   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c0cb:e470:91c7:abb9%14"
 [9] "   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.201.120.184"              
[10] "   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0"               
[11] "   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.201.120.253"              
[12] ""                                                                   
[13] "Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:"                            
[14] ""                                                                   
[15] "   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : tbglondon.local"             
[16] "   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9d9b:c44c:fd4d:1c77%11"
[17] "   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.201.120.157"              
[18] "   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0"               
[19] "   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.201.120.253"              
[20] ""                                                                   
[21] "Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 13:"                          
[22] ""                                                                   
[23] "   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected"          
[24] "   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : "                            
[25] ""                                                                   
[26] "Tunnel adapter isatap.tbglondon.local:"                             
[27] ""                                                                   
[28] "   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected"          
[29] "   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : tbglondon.local"             
[30] ""                                                                   
[31] "Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:"                  
[32] ""                                                                   
[33] "   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected"          
[34] "   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : "
```

Now you can use `grep` to find the lines with `IPv4`:

```
x[grep("IPv4", x)]
[1] "   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.201.120.184"
[2] "   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.201.120.157"
```

And to extract just the ip address:

```
z <- x[grep("IPv4", x)]
gsub(".*? ([[:digit:]])", "\\1", z)
"10.201.120.184" "10.201.120.157"
```

Comment: @user1983395 Welcome to SO. if this answer is helpful, please remember to accept it, by clicking the tick mark.

Comment: I try to use it from an online r application and get this error: Error in system("ipconfig", intern = TRUE) : error in running command. Any ideas about what's going wrong?

Comment: What OS are you running online? Most likely linux. You issued a DOS command.

Comment: For debian (and probably other linux distro) users: `strsplit(system('hostname -I',intern=T)," ")[[1]][1]` works perfectly

Comment: which one is the IP address a website I visit would see?

Answer (score 10):

I recently created a minimal package using `ipify.org` to do this exact thing.

Usage is easy, you can install using `devtools` and github.

`library(devtools)
install_github("gregce/ipify")`

once installed, its as easy as loading the library and one function call...

`library(ipify)
get_ip()`

Comment: This gets the public IP address of the machine. Is there a way to get the local IP address?

Answer (score 2):

Though @andrie explained it in very layman language and i am sure it helped us a lot to understand the functionality of it.

So from there only sharing a one liner code without installing any other package.

```
gsub(".*? ([[:digit:]])", "\\1", system("ipconfig", intern=T)[grep("IPv4", system("ipconfig", intern = T))])
```

Hope this would be helpful!

Comment: One liners are not very helpful when they are long, not DRY, and have nested brackets. See Martin Fowler's book on Refactoring.

Answer (score -5):

This retrieves exactly what you want:

```
system('ipconfig getifaddr en0')

192.168.1.73
```

Comment: your command doesn't work in R or in CMD window (on my Window 7 workstation). Could you please re-test it. May be it's just specific to your machine? It just returns an extensive help manual for `ipconfig` command.

Comment: That's also not working. Probably it was working in an older version of R or your IDE.