# How to get ip address using R?

Tags: r

How to get the IP address of the machine where the `R` code is running?

Could anyone tell me the R code of getting the IP address of the machine?

Thanks.

Comment: External IP, or Internal IP? On what operating system?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357219/function-for-retrieving-own-ip-address-from-within-r

Comment: Machines don't have IP addresses; interfaces/adapters do. Machines can have multiple interfaces/adapters. R does not posses the low-level system calls required to query interfaces/adapters directly. You must use shell commands.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft `nsl("localhost")` :P

Comment: Hey what bad person deleted my snarkyhumor comment?  :-(

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming here you're after your external IP address (as seen, for instance, by websites that you access). One option would be using a web service that provides your external IP address in an easily accessible format:

```
library(rjson)
fromJSON(readLines("http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php", warn=F))$ip
```

One downside of such an approach is that the website might go away, and then your code won't work.