# How to get the network properties in R

Tags: r

A command like `Sys.info()` gives me the node name, system name etc.

Is there anything similar to get the ***IPv4 address*** or the ***network name***?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe `system("ifconfig")` or `system("ipconfig")`?

Comment: This is in a previous question [Function for retrieving own ip address from within R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14357219/4752675)

Comment: system("ipconfig") worked for the IPv4, thanks @JasonAizkalns. It didn't show up in my research because I googled "get network configuration in R". It doesn't seem possible to get the wifi network name though.